# I got this error Unknown column 'Retail_Price' in 'field list'

Tags: php

```
        <?php           
                if(isset($_POST['insert']))
                {
                    echo $insert="insert into products (id,Product,Form,Strength,Generic_Name,Pack_Size,Retail_Price,Trade_Price) values
        ('','".$_POST['Product']."','".$_POST['Form']."','".$_POST['Strength']."','".$_POST['Generic_Name']."','".$_POST['Pack_Size']."','".$_POST['Retail_Price']."','".$_POST['Trade_Price']."')";
                    $query_insert=mysql_query($insert);
                    if($query_insert)
                    {
                        $msg2="Inserted Successfully" or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msg2="Product already exist";
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Are you certain the column in your table is exactly named Retail_Price?

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions (deprecated)

Comment: Welcome! Please read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist to make sure your question is powerfull

Answer (score 0):

Check your products table. In that table Retail_Price doesn't exit, so you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `id` column and it `null` value, assumed it is integer value and is `auto_increment`

```
    <?php 

                if(isset($_POST['insert']))
                {
                    echo $insert="insert into products (Product,Form,Strength,Generic_Name,Pack_Size,Retail_Price,Trade_Price) values
        ('".$_POST['Product']."','".$_POST['Form']."','".$_POST['Strength']."','".$_POST['Generic_Name']."','".$_POST['Pack_Size']."','".$_POST['Retail_Price']."','".$_POST['Trade_Price']."')";
                    $query_insert=mysql_query($insert);
                    if($query_insert)
                    {
                        $msg2="Inserted Successfully" or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msg2="Product already exist";
                        echo mysql_error();
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the field Retail_Price does not exist in products table or it is spelled differently.